# How To Make Param Query Grid Data In Uppercase

Tags: grid, uppercase

I am using Param Query Grid To Display TimeSheet Records.
I want to display first column of my grid(which is activity of timesheet) always in upper case.

```
obj.colModel = [{
    title : "Activity",
    width : 100,
    dataType : "String",
    align : "center",
    dataIndx : "activity",
    editable : "false",
    cls : "cellChange",
    editor : {
        type : 'select',
        valueIndx : "activityid",
        labelIndx : "activity",
        mapIndices : {
            "text" : "activity",
            "value" : "activityid"
        },

        options : [{
                "value" : "",
                "text" : ""
            }
        ],
    },

}, {
    title : "Month - Year",
    dataType : "string",
    align : "center",
    colModel : [{
            title : "MON/XX",
            width : 70,
            align : "center",
            dataIndx : "mon",
            dataType : "float",
            validations : [{
                    type : workHourValidity
                }, {
                    type : decimalValid
                }, ]
        }, {
            title : "TUE/XX",
            align : "center",
            dataIndx : "tue",
            dataType : "float",
            validations : [{
                    type : workHourValidity
                }, {
                    type : decimalValid
                }
            ]
        }, {
            title : "WED/XX",
            align : "center",
            dataIndx : "wed",
            dataType : "float",
            validations : [{
                    type : workHourValidity
                }, {
                    type : decimalValid
                }
            ]
        }, {
            title : "THU/XX",
            align : "center",
            dataIndx : "thu",
            dataType : "float",
            validations : [{
                    type : workHourValidity
                }, {
                    type : decimalValid
                }
            ]
        }, {
            title : "FRI/XX",
            align : "center",
            dataIndx : "fri",
            dataType : "float",
            validations : [{
                    type : workHourValidity
                }, {
                    type : decimalValid
                }
            ]
        }, {
            title : "SAT/XX",
            align : "center",
            dataIndx : "sat",
            dataType : "float",
            validations : [{
                    type : workHourValidity
                }, {
                    type : decimalValid
                }
            ]
        }, {
            title : "SUN/XX",
            align : "center",
            dataIndx : "sun",
            dataType : "float",
            validations : [{
                    type : workHourValidity
                }, {
                    type : decimalValid
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    title : "Description",
    dataIndx : "desc",
    dataType : "String",
    align : "center",
    editable : true,
    minWidth : 165,
    sortable : false,
    render : function (ui) {
        $(this).pqGrid("option", "wrap", false).tooltip();
        if (typeof ui.cellData == "undefined") {
            return "";
        } else {
            return '<span title ="' + ui.cellData + '">'
             + ui.cellData + '</span>';
        }
    }
}, {
    title : "",
    align : "center",
    editable : false,
    minWidth : 165,
    sortable : false,
    render : function (ui) {
        if (ui.rowData.nobtn) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return "<button type='button' class='delete_btn'>Delete</button>";
        }
    }
}, {
    title : "Act ID",
    dataType : "string",
    hidden : "true",
    align : "center",
    dataIndx : "activityid"
}, ];
```

Is there anyway we can make our grid data in uppercase

Answer (score 1):

use attribute 'render'

> obj.colModel = [{    title : "Activity",
>       width : 100,
>       dataType : "String",
>       align : "center",
>       dataIndx : "activity",
>       editable : "false",
>       cls : "cellChange", render: convertUpperCase} ]

```
function convertUpperCase(ui)  
    return ui.cellData.toUpperCase() ;
```